I am struggling with DataTables. For some reason, the data is not shown on the screen. But I can send data and they are accepted as valid
I cannot make my DataTable work.
No data is shown on the screen, only the main menu, the search field etc.
I send the data using Ajax and am sure that they arrive where they should - But the data is not displayed.
But if I do not send the data using ajax, they will appear in the tables in the screen.
This is my entire code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>DataTables Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <table id="example" class="display">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Position</td>
        <td>Office</td>
        <td>Age</td>
        <td>Start date</td>
        <td>Salary</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#example").DataTable({
      columns: [
        { title: "Name", data: "name" },
        { title: "Position", data: "Position" },
        { title: "Office", data: "Office" },
        { title: "Age", data: "Age" },
        { title: "Start Date", data: "StartDate" },  // Match JSON key
        { title: "Salami", data: "Salami" }
      ],
      ajax: {
        url: "dbr.php", // Replace with your server-side script URL
        type: "POST",
        data: function(d) {
          d.functionNumber = 98; // Add your function number to the request
          d.selectedRecordNumber = 1;
          d.length = 2;
        },
        success: function(response) {
          console.log("Response from dbr.php:", response);  
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.error("AJAX error:", status, error);
          console.log("XHR Response Text:", xhr.responseText); 
        },
        dataSrc: function(response) {
          console.log("Received data:", response);  
          return response;  
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>

I do not actually fetch the data from a database, instead I created them manually because I constantly got an errormessage saying that "[object Object]" is not valid JSON", or words to that effect.
I created two records where I manually made sure it was valid JSON.
Like this:
  // Attempt to create an object
  $O = array(
    "name" => "Jane Smith",
    "Position" => "Designer",
    "Office" => "København",
    "Age" => "30",
    "StartDate" => "2020-05-20",  // Notice the key has no spaces
    "Salami" => "150000"
  );
  $P = array(
    "name" => "Poul Smith",
    "Position" => "Designer",
    "Office" => "Copenhagen",
    "Age" => "30",
    "StartDate" => "2020-05-20",  // Notice the key has no spaces
    "Salami" => "150000"
  );
  $J = json_encode([$O, $P]);
  $b = ob_get_clean();

  // Set the content-type to JSON
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo $J;

And this is where I am now. I can send data, and DataTable acknowledges it has received them and that they are valid. But they are not shown.
I (hope) it is just me that has overlooked some activation thing or maybe made an error in the setup of the table or something.
Can anybody help me?
Best regards
Poul
PS. I can now send data I get from the database and so don't have to create data manually. Which means I can now get the data from my database without any trouble. But they are still not accepted by DataTables and shown in a table. Still blank screen.
